# Put submit button and input text on same line

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using Django and http://forms.viewflow.io/ .

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method='POST' action='' >
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='some value' />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 required" id="id_email_container">
                <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
                <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            </div>
        </div>
       <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn" value='Sign Up'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

How do I put the submit button next to text input?
I repeat I'm using **DJANGO.**

Comment: Can you change the layout of this form, or is this the default layout and you can only add css?

Comment: @PaigeMeinke This is the default layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position the button absolutely. I changed the input to have a responsive width, but if it is a set width, that would be even easier for you. Make it left:  whatever the width of the input + label are plus a little extra for margin.

```css
form button{
  position:absolute;
  left:80%;
  top:0;
}
#id_email{
  width:60%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid">

     <form method='POST' action='' >

      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='some value' />


<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col-sm-12 required" id="id_email_container">
        <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
        <label for="id_email">Email</label>

    </div>
</div>


       <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn" value='Sign Up'>Submit</button>

     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could use `float:left` or `display:inline-block` on the `.row` ( select only the specific row inside the form ) . Both of them work

See snippet below with `display:inline-block`

```css
form > input + .row {
 display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form method='POST' action='' >
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='some value' />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 required" id="id_email_container">
                <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
                <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            </div>
        </div>
       <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn" value='Sign Up'>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you want it exactly, but you can play with the margin.

```css
.row {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form method='POST' action='' >
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='some value' />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 required" id="id_email_container">
                <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
                <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            </div>
        </div>
       <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn" value='Sign Up'>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With simply the following :

```
<div>
<form method='POST' action='' >
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='some value' />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12 required" id="id_email_container">
            <label for="id_email">Email</label>
            <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email">
            <button type="submit" name="_submit" class="btn" value='Sign Up'>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

All i did was re-arrange the lines you made.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching this now, [crispy](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) has a really clean solution to append a button to an input field if you're also using bootstrap. In your forms.py:

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FieldWithButtons, StrictButton
from django import forms

class FieldWithButtonForm(forms.Form):
    field_with_button = forms.CharField()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FieldWithButtonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            FieldWithButtons('field_with_button', StrictButton('Submit', type='submit', css_class='btn btn-primary'))
```

Note: If you're trying to submit your form with this control then you have to explicitly set type='submit' or the button will render as type='button'

more on crispy layouts [here.](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html)